# Length versus Character Set Size in Brute Force Password Cracking

Tags: r

### Background

I'm involved in creating a group presentation and paper for a college class where our hypothesis is that password length is more important than character sets included in a password. Our research into things like the "Password Haystack" Calculator (can't link, not enough rep) tell us that length should become more important than complexity (or character sets included) in the password. For example, while "#dA6,!pd%6" is strong, "aaabbbcccaaabbbcccaaabbbcccaaabbbcccaaabbbccc" is stronger, simply because an adversary does not know any prior knowledge what a user has chosen, besides the websites requirements.

We have written several programs, one that creates random passwords of varying lengths and including various character sets (a-z, 0-9, symbols, A-Z) and another that inputs various passwords and computes the required number of brute force tries to arrive at the correct guess.

Using R I have generated some pretty graphics, for example [image: Brute force violin plot for eight character passwords on a log y scale]. Since uppercase is the last set to be searched, all uppercase only passwords having the largest iteration values makes sense.

[image: Brute force heat map for various character factors and password length, given on log scale for iterations as color]
This graph also makes sense to me, there is variation depending on the character sets, with those in the upper reaches of the character sets having more calculated iterations, and password length contributing as well to all of them.

Running a two-way ANOVA test on the Rockyou database (32 million real stolen plain text passwords) with a given passwords keyspace location versus both character sets and length returns

```
# Two-way ANOVA
> rockyou17.anova <- aov(location ~ length*charSet,   data=rockyou17)

> summary(rockyou17.anova)

                     Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    

length                1 1.209e+68 1.209e+68   50209 <2e-16 ***

charSet              14 1.179e+68 8.419e+66    3498 <2e-16 ***

length:charSet       14 1.341e+69 9.581e+67   39804 <2e-16 ***

Residuals      14245361 3.429e+70 2.407e+63  

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The p-values (Pr>F), if I understand it, means that both character sets and password length are immensely important. This makes sense to me, since the keyspace location is calculated based entirely on character set and password length. However, I'm way out of my league and we did not have time to even discuss Chi-square tests this summer in my Applied Statistics class.

### Questions

1. How can we prove, or show a stronger relationship for length versus character set/radix?
2. Is this something that is more adapt at theoretical mathematics?
3. Given a real world database set of 14 million unique passwords, besides interesting data like password length histograms and percentage of character sets used, what else could I tease out of such a set?

I attempted to contact several professors at my college, but the only one that others deemed qualified was sick last week, and this week is behind playing catch up for last week, and so is unable to help.

(I had to pare down the background information considerably to allow this to post. My apologies if it is lacking in the necessary details.)

Comment: as someone in "non-China" cyber research, might i suggest not [reinventing the wheel](http://www.guanotronic.com/~serge/papers/chi11b.pdf). we could really use more papers on vuln mgmt or risk mgmt.

Comment: I found many good links in that folder. Unfortunately this is an English class, not a Computer Science class. I'm limited with what I can research and present to a non-technologically inclined audience. I'd actually love to go into the cyber security field, but am severly limited in what I can present, with background, in a four page, double-spaced paper and 8 minutes of presentation. This includes laying the background of what keyspace is, brute force attacking, etc. We had to brutally narrow our field but would have liked to do more. This is really more a topic for a term paper or thesis

Comment: I have attempted to use R to calculate the probability of finding a password as the brute force continues from start to end. Similar to guessing a single digit from 0-9 with `phyper(0:9, 9, 1, 1:10)` which seems off. Yet if I calculate it manually (I hope correctly) `(1/7)*(7/8)*(8/9)*(9/10)` I get the same. That is the probability your fourth guess is correct, given 3 previous incorrect answers. I get a list of 0.1's, yet this seems counter intuitive. What is the accumulated probability of guessing. If I start at 0 and work my way to 9, surely by the last guess I have to have found it! In R?

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothesis is generally true, but you have to consider the caveat that it is not an absolute rule.  In your comparison of the random 10 character password and the longer string of repeating, sequential alphabetical characters you are correct that a normal brute force attack will find the shorter random string much faster than the patterned one.  However, if an attacker is trying patterns or if the base string "aaabbbccc" appears in a dictionary file used by an attacker it will be much faster to find it than the random string.

So the potential variety of attacks that realistically could be run against a password have an impact on its strength.  For your paper you could assume that only brute force attacks will be conducted, but that's not an accurate reflection of what happens in the real world.

An ideal secure password is one in which a brute force attack is the fastest attack likely to crack it while also having enough possible combinations to make success with that brute force attack computationally infeasible.  It tends to be easier to increase potential combinations by adding length to a password rather than adding characters to your potential character set.  As I think you figured out the character set acts as a base while the length acts as an exponent.  So adding one to the character set has a linear effect and adding one to the length has an exponential effect on the number of possible passwords.

But that only holds true when the character selected don't take the form of words, patterns, or other predictable choices that allow an attacker to focus on a much smaller percentage of password choices.

In your violin plot you seem to indicate that all uppercase character passwords are extremely strong (at least as far as iterations required to guess them), but that is also due to your specific approach to guessing them.  If an attacker starts with uppercase characters and ends with lowercase your data would flip flop.  Generally we try to avoid that problem by assuming the attacker is limiting their guesses to the appropriate character set.  That means data like that of your lowercase and uppercase sets should look the same iteration wise.

Alternatively you could assume an attacker is going to attack character sets in order based on the lowest maximum iterations.  So they'd start with something like D, L, U, LD, UD, etc.  Although if you are using this to determine your iteration count it still has the problem of needing to choose an character set order which is not consistent.

I do like your idea of gathering data on how the character sets percentages change with password length.  The character sets chosen can provide very basic feedback on possible strength, which could help you determine if your hypothesis is true.

You can also assess how the password character mask or topology changes with length.  A passwords like "Royals15" has a mask of ULLLLLDD, which gives you more info about the password than just the character set.  Greater variety in masks within a sample tends to indicate stronger passwords were chosen, so that might also give you data on the strength of passwords at different lengths.

If you have the time you might even consider submitting the passwords to CMU's [Password Guessing Service](https://pgs.ece.cmu.edu/) to get a more precise rating of their strength at the different lengths.  This would probably be the most accurate rating of those discussed above.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, and wish I could have added more to my initial question, but then it was flagged as spam. The problem as I see it is this is a giant rabbit hole, guessing attackers motives or dictionaries. As this is an English class and given only 4 pages double spaced, and 8 minutes to present our finding plus the technical background we're swamped as it is. Also, this is an exercise in presenting and writing a scientific paper, so I feel we're in the right ball park. However, I would have felt more comfortable with some numbers to back up the general trend.